@Scheduled jobs can not find "sql tables" because flyway migrate is running before each test case
I have created junit 5 annotation to clean and migrate my database before each test using flyway. Here is the reference: blog
In my application, I have also scheduled jobs. In the integration tests (using @SpringBootTest) when scheduler jobs run, it fails because flyway cleared the database and scheduled job has no aware of it. For each db call it says: " o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "test_table" does not exist"
How can i fix this?
Here is the annotation:
@Slf4j
public class ClearDatabaseBeforeEachCallback implements BeforeEachCallback {

    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        log.info("Clear database before each request :'{}'", context.getDisplayName());
        clearFlyway(context);

    }

    private void clearFlyway(ExtensionContext context) {
        Flyway flyway = SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(context)
                .getBean(Flyway.class);
        flyway.clean();
        flyway.migrate();
    }
}

@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ExtendWith(ClearDatabaseBeforeEachCallback.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.flyway.clean-disabled=false")
public @interface ClearDatabaseBeforeEach {
}

Here is the example test case:
@ClearDatabaseBeforeEach
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public abstract class BaseSpringBootTest extends BaseIntegrationTest {
}

public class AppFlowTest extends BaseSpringBootTest {
   
    @Test
    void anyTest() {
        // any test that can longer than the first scheduled runner
        // while the test runs, scheduled job is called in another thread
        // or scheduled job is called, just after the first test is finished and just before the second test case is started
    }
}


Maybe you could a lock between flyway & TestCase.
Could use CountDownLatch class.
Some code examples, may not be executable.
public class ClearDatabaseBeforeEachCallback implements BeforeEachCallback {

    public static CountDownLatch latch;

    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    
        log.info("Clear database before each request :'{}'", context.getDisplayName());
        clearFlyway(context);
    
        latch.countDown();
    }
}

then add wait in your test code:
public class AppFlowTest extends BaseSpringBootTest {
   
    @Test
    void anyTest() {
        ClearDatabaseBeforeEachCallback.latch.await();

        //your test code
    }
}

But this is a very raw idea, you could experiment with it for more further.
